# How to restart a docker service using Shell Script

Tags: node.js, shell, docker, sh, docker-compose

- I have `Node` service which is running in Docker container

  - Due following exception service gets stopped after some time.

`events.js:141 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: read ECONNRESET
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
        at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:544:26)`

- I am not aware why this exception is coming up.
- I am looking for work around which can restart the service once its stop.
- I am using `shell` file to run these service, So is there something that I can add in shell file which can restart this stopped service.

Here is a sample of my shell file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ORGANISATION="$1"
SERVICE_NAME="$2"
VERSION="$3"
ENVIRONMENT="$4"
INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$5"
EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$6"
NETWORK="$7"
docker build -t ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION} --build-arg PORT=${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT} --no-cache .
docker stop ${SERVICE_NAME}
docker rm ${SERVICE_NAME}

sudo npm install
sudo npm install -g express
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --restart always --name ${SERVICE_NAME} -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs npm nodejs-legacy vim

RUN mkdir /database_service
ADD . /database_service
WORKDIR /database_service

RUN npm install -g path
RUN npm cache clean

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: trying to understand your problem, is the service inside the container is stopped or the container itself is stopped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `docker run --restart always ...`. Then Docker will restart the container every time it is stopped.

The error comes from a tcp connection that is abruptly closed, maybe from a database or websocket.

I don't know why you use npm in your script, because it is outside of the container. If you want it to be installed inside the container add it to a `RUN` in your Dockerfile.

Maybe take a look at docker-compose. With it you can write your config in a `docker-compose.yml` file and simply use `docker-compose up --build` and have the same functionality as this script.

Comment: Yes . . . . . .

Comment: Why do you not use the `node` base image

Comment: Thanks `--restart always` fix my problem as workaround approach. But its temporary fix.